# How to upload a file in SafariDriver / Safari using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari

Hi can you help me with uploading a file in Safari ,Mac OS.

I have given a site were we can upload the following types of file by clicking "Choose File" Button(JPG, PNG, GIF, DOC, XLS, PDF, ZIP, RAR, ZIPX)

```
package Default;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class Safari_demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(6000);

        driver.get("http://www.files.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("uploadFields")).click();

        //can you please help me with code in this line 
        //this is the place were i need to enter the address of the
        //file which is in my system  

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("youruploadbuttonid")).sendKeys("yourpicturelocalpath");

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that SafariDriver doesn't support file uploads: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4220

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='uploadFields']/input"))
                .sendKeys(
                        "your image path");
```

Answer (score -1):

So the file upload dialog is really a native system dialog not a web one, hence you can not interact with it using Selenium. The way to do it locally is to send the path to filePath textbox, saucelabs describes it pretty well:

> For those of you doing this locally, all you need to do is use the
>   sendKeys command to type the local path of the file in any file field.
>   This works like a charm in all drivers. When moving this test to a
>   remote server (such as, for example, our Selenium 2 Cloud), all you
>   need to do is use the setFileDetector method to let WebDriver know
>   that you’re uploading files from your local computer to a remote
>   server instead of just typing a path. Almost magically, the file will
>   be base64 encoded and sent transparently through the JSON Wire
>   Protocol for you before writing the fixed remote path. This is an
>   excellent solution, as it lets you switch your tests from a local to
>   remote Driver without having to worry about changing your tests’ code.

https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload